# Make JSON php request from Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, request, firefox-addon

i'm writing a Firefox addon on sdk, i need to use in my main function an array. this array contains a list of data located in my BD. that’s why im using a php file to connect  the BD  and echo data in JSON format . then i call back the php file using request function and finally parse  the JSON to an array. (my problem is how to request the php file and parse the json to array ) i tryed
`var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;`
`var function = Request({`
 `url: "file.php",`
  `onComplete: function (response) {`
  `var arrray = response.json;`

`}`
`});`

but that didn't work :/ 
i tried a lot of thing too . 
could someone help me with the right function to request the php file then parse the json to array
`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need the full URL to your PHP script on your server.

Comment: i can't try it in my localhost to test it before uploding the php to the server ?

Comment: You should be able to, but you will need the full url to it in your plugin.

Comment: thats the problem, i try it using this but it didn't work, i'm sure i have a problem with the function now :/